# Make indicator-cpufreq start automatically with "Performance" mode Xubuntu 22.04

Tags: xubuntu, cpu

Every time the system is started, the mode is reset to "schedule". I need the mode to always be set to "Performance". In other words: so that the change of mode to "Performance", which I made manually, could withstand a system restart.
Thank you.

Comment: What mode? Where? Your question needs some details. What commands did you use please give exact details.

Comment: @David Thank you for answer. But I can't give much more specifics. In short, I installed the indicator-cpufreq application, which subsequently appeared on my taskbar. This application allows you to use the GUI to modify the frequency of the processor, based on different modes: conservative, ondemand, powersave, schedutil and PERFORMANCE. Every time the computer is restarted, the application automatically starts with the "schedule" mode, regardless of which mode I choose during the system run. Is it clear now?

Comment: @David I simply want the application to start at system startup with the mode I chose !during the last PC session!. So that I don't have to change the mode every time.